# Is it possible to make FF Reader View default for normal browsing?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is it possible to make FF Reader View default for normal browsing? I've looked in about:config and only see 1 line regarding.

Comment: Would have to make addon to do this, good idea, are you into addon making?

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

I also understand why they do it.  But I disagree.  If the pages don't load well, then it is (or should be) an option for the user to load the full page.  That is, consider it to be a toggle, where each page can be "reader view" or "standard view" and the user can easily switch between then.  Then the question is just which is default.  Once loaded, the other option can be selected, if the page is too ugly in the view that is chosen.

Answer (score -2):

There are times I wish the same.  However, I understand why they don't do it:  If you click on a link - for example on the news.google.com page, when you click on the reader view, you get a message, "Automatic content extraction failed" due to the layout and multiple pictures/headings in columns. If you're on the main Google News page and click on a link and then click on the Reader View, you get mixed results - some articles render well, others don't accept the rerendering. Other pages I've viewed - main page of cnsnews.com for instance, will attempt to render in reader view but it is butt ugly. So, it is tough to "always" show in reader view.